# ggplot2 geom_smooth, extended model for method=lm

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use `geom_smooth` to get a fitted line from a certain linear regression model.

It seems to me that the formula can only take `x` and `y` and not any additional parameter.

To show more clearly what I want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(35413)
df <- data.frame(pred = runif(100,10,100),
           factor = sample(c("A","B"), 100, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(
    outcome = 100 + 10*pred + 
    ifelse(factor=="B", 200, 0) + 
    ifelse(factor=="B", 4, 0)*pred +
    rnorm(100,0,60))
```

With

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=pred, y=outcome, color=factor)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=factor)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_bw()
```

I produce fitted lines that, due to the `color=factor` option, are basically the output of the linear model `lm(outcome ~ pred*factor, df)`

[image]

In some cases, however, I prefer the lines to be the output of a different model fit, like `lm(outcome ~ pred + factor, df)`, for which I can use something like:

```
fit <- lm(outcome ~ pred+factor, df)
predval <- expand.grid(
  pred = seq(
    min(df$pred), max(df$pred), length.out = 1000),
  factor = unique(df$factor)) %>%
  mutate(outcome = predict(fit, newdata = .))

ggplot(df, aes(x=pred, y=outcome, color=factor)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = predval) +
  theme_bw()
```

which results in :

[image]

My question: is there a way to produce the latter graph exploiting the `geom_smooth` instead? I know there is a `formula =` - option in `geom_smooth` but I can't make something like `formula = y ~ x + factor` or `formula = y ~ x + color` (as I defined `color = factor`) work.

Comment: No, I don't think you can. Each `stat` is done groupwise, in this case separate `lm` calls are done per level of `factor`. Note that this is not exactly the same as `lm(outcome ~ pred*factor,df)`, as I think the confidence bands will look different.

Comment: If I put color=factor outside the aes-statement, it wouldn't be grouped and the stat would apply to the complete data I believe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot linear regressions lines without interaction in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722905/plot-linear-regressions-lines-without-interaction-in-ggplot2). Related: [Constraining slope in stat_smooth with ggplot (plotting ANCOVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251294/constraining-slope-in-stat-smooth-with-ggplot-plotting-ancova); [ggplot2: Plotting regression lines with different intercepts but with same slope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903606/ggplot2-plotting-regression-lines-with-different-intercepts-but-with-same-slope)

Comment: I think that the easiest way is to use the `broom::augment`. E.g. ```model1 <- lm(outcome~pred+factor,df)

broom::augment(model1, df) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = pred, color = factor)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=outcome)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted))```

Comment: If you put `color = factor` outside the `aes` statement you'll get an error. Aesthetic mapping to column names can only be put in `aes`. Only fixed aesthetic effects such as `color = 'red'` can be put outside.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. Probably the main reason why `geom_smooth` is so "resistant" to allowing custom models of multiple variables is that it is limited to producing 2-D curves; consequently, its arguments are designed for handling two-dimensional data (i.e. formula = response variable ~ independent variable).

The trick to getting what you requested is using the `mapping` argument within `geom_smooth`, instead of `formula`. As you've probably seen from looking at the [documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html#arguments), `formula` only allows you to specify the mathematical structure of the model (e.g. linear, quadratic, etc.). Conversely, the `mapping` argument allows you to directly specify new y-values - such as the output of a custom linear model that you can call using `predict()`.

Note that, by default, `inherit.aes` is set to `TRUE`, so your plotted regressions will be coloured appropriately by your categorical variable. Here's the code:

```
# original plot
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=pred, y=outcome, color=factor)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=factor)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  ggtitle("outcome ~ pred") +
  theme_bw()

# declare new model here
plm <- lm(formula = outcome ~ pred + factor, data=df)

# plot with lm for outcome ~ pred + factor
plot2 <-ggplot(df, aes(x=pred, y=outcome, color=factor)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=factor)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", mapping=aes(y=predict(plm,df))) +
  ggtitle("outcome ~ pred + factor") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this solution give proper estimation errors? My understanding is that it doesn't, I'm afraid.